# Understanding the output from the fast Fourier transform method

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm trying to make sense of the output produced by the python FFT library.

I have a sqlite database where I have logged several series of ADC values. Each series consist of 1024 samples taken with a frequency of 1 ms.

After importing a dataseries, I normalize it and run int through the `fft` method. I've included a few plots of the original signal compared to the FFT output.

```
import sqlite3
import struct
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time
import math

conn = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\my_test_data.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT ID, time, data_blob FROM log_tbl')


for row in c:
    data_raw = bytes(row[2])
    data_raw_floats = struct.unpack('f'*1024, data_raw)
    data_np = np.asarray(data_raw_floats)

    data_normalized = (data_np - data_np.mean()) / (data_np.max() - data_np.min())

    fft = np.fft.fft(data_normalized)
    N = data_normalized .size

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(data_normalized )

    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(np.abs(fft)[:N // 2] * 1 / N)
    plt.show()

    plt.clf()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

The signal clearly contains some frequencies, and I was expecting them to be visible from the FFT output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That makes sense. The result wasn't what I was expecting to see, so I've had a feeling that I was messing something up. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Might be useful: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Had a new thing in mind, I delete my comment and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that your data is evenly spaced when using `np.fft.fft`, otherwise the output will not be accurate. If they are not evenly spaced, you can use LS periodograms for example: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/stats/lombscargle.html.
Or look up non-uniform fft.

About the plots:
I don't think that you are doing something obviously wrong. Your signal consists a signal with period in the order of magnitude `100`, so you can expect a strong frequency signal around `1/period=0.01`. This is what is visible on your graphs. The time-domain signals are not that sinusoidal, so your peak in the frequency domain will be blurry, as seen on your graphs.